# Django Model Fields Radio Button

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

how can i create a radio button using Django model fields

```
#models.py

GENDER_CHOICES = (
   ('M', Male),
   ('F', 'Female')
)

class Profile(models.Model):
     gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=128)
```

the above field is rendering as a select field, But i want to make it as 
 a radio button.

If the question is not correct, somebody please correct the question

Answer (score 14):

Default widget for choice field is choice/selection list.
you can change widget in form

```
 gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

Comment: how can i do it in model field instead of form

Comment: you can do it, you had to override default model implementation, please follow the link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#specifying-the-form-field-for-a-model-field

Comment: @thameem if you find my answer okay, mark it correct, this will increase my points.

Comment: 'django.db.models' has no 
attribute 'ChoiceField' can you explain?

Comment: not  to use on django model

Comment: Another way I found of doing it in the model filed is by 
GENDER_CHOICES = (
   ('M', Male),
   ('F', 'Female')
)

gender_choices = models.CharField(max_length=(put a number that makes sense), choices=GENDER_CHOICES).
I hope this will help.

Answer (score 4):

## This works for Django 2.1 and up

models.py keep unchanged

In admin.py

```
   from django.contrib import admin 

   class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   fields = (......, 'gender',...)

   radio_fields = {'gender': admin.VERTICAL}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean [enumeration types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices)

```html
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Student(models.Model):

    class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
        FRESHMAN = 'FR', _('Freshman')
        SOPHOMORE = 'SO', _('Sophomore')
        JUNIOR = 'JR', _('Junior')
        SENIOR = 'SR', _('Senior')
        GRADUATE = 'GR', _('Graduate')

    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YearInSchool.choices,
        default=YearInSchool.FRESHMAN,
    )

    def is_upperclass(self):
        return self.year_in_school in {
            self.YearInSchool.JUNIOR,
            self.YearInSchool.SENIOR,
        }
```